# In my webpage done in angular I am able to scroll but scroll bars are missing:

Tags: html, angular

In my webpage done in angular I am able to scroll but scroll bars are missing:

Comment: can be hidden with the help of CSS

Comment: i have tried adding a div after the header and given overflow-y:scroll auto etc but that also didnt work

Comment: my requirement is to get the scrollbar..now it is missing

Comment: These must be some CSS issue with your code

Comment: how can I find that.. I have tried searching for overflow:hidden property but have not given anything like that

Comment: May help you out https://stackoverflow.com/q/16670931/5043867

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link. I have given ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0 !important
}    this caused the issue..

Comment: Glad to know :)